# Only name without surname diplays in contacts after importing them from Google

Tags: contacts, blu-win-hd

I've had my contacts in a .vcf file, I imported them to Google and then imported from Google to my phone (BLU win hd). Now in my contact list only first names are displayed without surnames as in picture here:

[image]

When I enter contact details I can see full name at the top:

[image]

How can I make it display full names in my contact list? As you can see it's pretty confusing if I have more friends with same name :0

Comment: This is strange, the People app should show both first and last names. Try opening one of the contacts, tap the Edit button, then tap the **+** icon next to the name. This will show you the individual "components" of the name. Make sure the surname is in the correct field, and not in the middle name field, for example.

Comment: Is there a reason that you didn't just connect your phone to your Google account directly, instead of exporting as a vcf, and reimporting?

Comment: @RowlandShaw The way I understand, the contacts were imported to Google, and then the phone was connected to the Google account. That's why the second screenshot shows "Google" as the source under the contact's name.

Answer (score 3):

Per my comment, this can happen when the surname is in the wrong field, for instance, in the middle name field. Observe:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The screenshots are from Windows 10 Mobile, but the effect is the same in Windows Phone 8.x as well.

To fix, simply open each of the contacts, tap the Edit button, then tap the **+** icon next to the name field. This will give you the form shown in the first screenshot, where you can edit the individual "components" of the name. Make sure the first and last name are in the correct fields.

Answer (score 1):

That is because the **Middle name** is not displayed in the people app and is only displayed when you open a contact's profile.

Surname should be displayed in your people's list. See the example below,

[image: Example contact in people list]

[image: Contact example profile]

---

### Solution 1

1. Open contact profile
2. Click edit contact
3. Edit the name

[image]

4. Make sure that the name you want as surname is in surname.

---

### Solution 2

As you are importing directly from a .csv file, edit the .csv file such that the name you want to display is not in the middle name.

---